# jQuery Validation plug-in – turning off validation based on class attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How can I instruct jQuery Validation plug-in to turn off validation based on class attributes and just work based on json rules?

This is conflicting with my jQuery templating system.

Answer (score 2):

First, in your JQuery ready function set the class to 'ignore' or 'require' for each element:

```
$("#name").attr("class", "required");
$("#email").attr("class", "ignore");
```

Second, set validate function to ignore the 'ignore' class:

```
$("#form1").validate({ignore: ".ignore"});
```

This will require the name but ignore the email.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of jquery.validate.js, there is a variable called classRuleSettings, which stores the validation types based on class names. Set it to a 0 length array and you shold be good.

Try this():

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="required"/>
    <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.validator.classRuleSettings = []; //I am not sure about any side effects because of this
  $("form").validate();
</script>
```

Comment: This is the ONLY response which answer the question.
The ignore part has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use ignore option

```
$("form").validate({ignore:".ignore"});

<input type="text" id="fName" class="required ignore"/>  <!--fname won't be "required"-->
```